# Rails Aptana 3 Go to Haml View Shortcut

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, aptana, aptana3

I am using Aptana as my Rails text editor.

When I am in a controller action "new for example" and I want to navigate to the view "new.html.**erb**" I press "Alt+ctr+shift+down" then I can navigate to the **erb** view.

However, when I am using **haml** and try the same, Aptana searches for "new.html.**erb**" not "new.html.**haml**" and displays **"view file not found"**

How can I tell Aptana that I am using **haml** views not **erb**?

Answer (score 0):

please do the following:

select the method name and press the following. You will reach the view.

shift + ctrl + v